# Unable to access Wordpress functions from functions.php

Tags: php, theme-development

I am following a tutorial in an attempt to create a custom theme on Wordpress. I created my functions.php file in my theme folder, and am attempting to use the Wordpress function 'wp_enqueue_style()' from functions.php. 'wp_enqueue_style()' is not working or populating on my text-editor, in fact, none of the functions starting in 'wp_' are working in my functions.php.

I checked the source of the wp_enqueue_style() function, which is 'includes/function.wp-styles', and it IS included in my directory, and I also tried using require_once('path to includes/function.wp-styles'); to link to that file from within functions.php.

I am totally clueless at this point...thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

check your `header.php` it should contain `<?php wp_head(); ?>` before the closing `</head>` tag.

check your `footer.php` it should contain `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` before the closing `</body>` tag.

You also need to hook your function to `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook and then add `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` inside that function. e.g;

```
function add_theme_scripts_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', 'path_to_the_style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', 'path_to_the_script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts_styles' );
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I had not done that yet but it did not help. can you think of any other reason why I wouldn't be able to use the wp_enqueue_style() function?

Comment: i mean check your header.php file there you should have `<?php wp_head(); ?>` before closing `</head>` and also check your footer.php file you should also have `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` function before `</body>`

Comment: missing `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` does not enqueue the scripts and styles.

Comment: you also need to hook your function to `wp_enqueue_scripts` and then add `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` inside that function. e.g;

`function add_theme_scripts_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', 'path_to_the_style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', 'path_to_the_script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts_styles' );`

Comment: welcome, please cast your vote :-)

Comment: what do you mean cast my vote? is there somewhere I can hook you up with an upvote or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44183/discussion-between-talentedaamer-and-candypaintedrims).